# Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, syntax-error

**I got a problem,**
Please help me on this
Error : Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key '

*MyAction Code*

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GiderEkle(Faturalar fatura, Giderler gideriki)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> item8 = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var c in db.Caris)
        {
            item8.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = c.Adi,
                Value = c.CariID.ToString()
            });

        }

        ViewBag.countrydrop = item8;

        return View();
    }
```

*My .cshtml Code*

```
<div class="form-group">
        <p>Müşterı Adı</p>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("country",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country,"Select country")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CariID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Model Cari,

```
public class Cari
{
    [Key]
    public int CariID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownItems { get; set; }
    public bool MusteriTip { get; set; }
    public string Unvan { get; set; }
    public string TC { get; set; }
    public string Adi { get; set; }
    public string Soyadi { get; set; }
    public string Adres { get; set; }
    public string VD { get; set; }
    public string VKN { get; set; }
    public string Telefon { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
}
```

Faturalar model,

```
public class Faturalar
{
    [Key]
    public int FaturaID { get; set; }
    public string Tarih { get; set; }
    public int CariID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CariID")]
    public Cari Caris { get; set; }
    public int FaturaNo { get; set; }
    public List<Giderler> Giderlers { get; set; }
}
```

Giderler model,

```
 public class Giderler
{
    [Key]
    public int GiderlerID { get; set; }
    public int FaturaID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FaturaID")]
    public Faturalar Faturalar { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }
    public int Miktar { get; set; }
    public string Birim { get; set; }
    public double Fiyat { get; set; }
    public double KDV { get; set; }
    public double Tutar { get; set; }
}
```

*and finally on the up side*

```
@model UmtKontrolMerkezi.Models.Faturalar
```

Answer (score 2):

The ViewBag property is called `countrydrop` and you are attempting to cast `ViewBag.country` to an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which does not exist.

You could use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("country",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrydrop,"Select country")
```

Which would reference the correct variable you have defined within your GiderEkle `Action Method`, however I would prefer a strongly typed view model over the `ViewBag` approach.

I have proved this works by the following Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/xXnQwy

**Action Method:**

```
    public ActionResult DropDownListTest()
    {
        var myList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        myList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Darren one", Value = "1" });
        myList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Darren two", Value = "2" });
        myList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Darren three", Value = "3" });

        ViewBag.DarrenList = myList;

        return View();
    }
```

**CSHTML file:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("DarrenId",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DarrenList)
```

Comment: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key

Comment: @GündoğduYakıcı - please see my dotnetfiddle and additional code

Comment: I'm pulling from the database

Comment: @GündoğduYakıcı - that doesn't matter, you can use your database values in the Text and Value properties as shown in my code.

Comment: @GündoğduYakıcı, This answer is correct, and if your still getting the error its because the ViewBag property is `null` - probably because you submit the form and then return the view, but have not repopulated the `ViewBag` property But your code makes no sense - based on the view you showed, it should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m = m.CariID, Model.DropDownItems)` and you set the `DropDownItems` property.